# TDE do we need to backup service master key (SMK) and database master key (DMK) on the DR server /Test Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to implement TDE by following the below steps

On Source Server: Service master key already exists

1. Create Master key  on Master database
2. Create Certificate   on Master database
3. Create database encryption key on the user database and enable TDE on this database
4. Backup certificate (.cer) with private key(.pvk)  with password

When I need to restore this TDE enabled database on DR/Test server

Test Server:

1. Create the certificate form the backup of the source server
2. Restore the database

I have found that we can take backups of Service Master Key(SMK) and Database Master Key (DMK) as well.

My questions are:

1. Why do we need to take backups of SMK and DMK? Just the certificate backup file .cer with private key file .pvk and password not enough?
2. Will I need the same SMK and DMK from sources server to restore the database backup on a test/DR server?
3. Why in the article below did they not restore SMK and DMK?

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3572/recovering-a-sql-server-tde-encrypted-database-successfully/

On a test server if a service master key already exists from SQL installation.

If I create a database master key (do I need to restore form the backup of source)

Then the next steps are simply restoring the certificate form the source server and then restore the database?

Please shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: you don't need to back up the DMK or SMK from the source server in order to be able to restore your database; the certificate is sufficient.

The longer answer is each of the SMK and DMK are designed to encrypt something in the [encryption hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encryption-hierarchy?view=sql-server-2017). In the case of TDE, the master database's DMK encrypts the private key portion of the TDE certificate. And the master database's DMK is encrypted by the SMK. This allows SQL to open the certificate without user intervention which in turn allows your database to *start* without user intervention. So long as you have a backup of the certificate that includes both the public and private key portions, you can restore that to any server you want and encrypt the private key portion with the target server's master database DMK and you should be g2g.

One caveat specific to DMKs and Availability Groups is that if you have a user database that's in an AG that has a DMK, you'll want the SMK to be the same across all of the servers in the AG. To make a physical lock analogy, you're putting a lock on the DMK's private key and making sure that all of the servers have a copy of the same key. If you *don't* do that, when you fail over, the new primary server's key won't fit in the lock and you'll have to open it with a key you have (i.e. the password) and then re-key the lock (i.e. `alter master key add encryption by service master key`).

Comment: Ok Thank you Ben Thul.

Comment: That said, you should test the restore of your database to another server to make sure *you* can do it. Document the steps. Where are you going to get the certificate from in case of a disaster? Et cetera.